# Combine Graphs in Networkx: Adding Graphs as Daughter Nodes

Tags: networkx, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have two Graphs.

Graph_1 is a Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG) which has the following edge list in df_1:

```
node_1  node_2
John    Charity
John    Constantine
Gordon  John
Gordon  Nick

Graph_1 = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df_1, source="node_1", 
                                       target="node_2", create_using=nx.DiGraph())
```

Graph_2 is a random stochastic graph which is generated as follows:

```
Graph_2 = nx.erdos_renyi_graph(1000, 0.1)
```

I would like to join Graph_2 to Graph_1 by making the node with the highest betweenness centrality in Graph_2 a child node of the "Nick" node in Graph_1.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I could do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following should work

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pylab as pl

edge_list = [
    ["John", "Charity"],
    ["John", "Constantine"],
    ["Gordon", "John"],
    ["Gordon", "Nick"], ]

Graph_1 = nx.from_edgelist(edge_list, create_using=nx.DiGraph())

# reduced the number for visualization
Graph_2 = nx.erdos_renyi_graph(10, 0.1)

node_with_highest_betweenness_centrality = max(nx.betweenness_centrality(Graph_2).items(), key=lambda x: x[1])[0]

joined_graph = nx.DiGraph(Graph_1)

joined_graph.add_edges_from(Graph_2.edges())
# not sure which direction you want
joined_graph.add_edge(node_with_highest_betweenness_centrality, "Nick")

nx.draw(joined_graph, with_labels=True)
pl.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi thank you for the pointers. Almost there; I am looking for a connection from Nick to the elements of Graph_2; i.e. the exact same graph with the arrows connecting Nick to Graph_2 elements pointing in the opposite direction. How would I go about that final step?

Comment: Ok. Figured it out: joined_graph.add_edge("Nick", node_with_highest_betweenness_centrality)